# What are RSPEC Stubs? By example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stub

I just can't seem to get a hold of what exactly stubs are.

Could someone just explain what the following RSPEC code is supposed to do. And what is the benefit of using stub here?

```
require "performance_monitor"

require "time"  # loads up the Time.parse method -- do NOT create time.rb!

describe "Performance Monitor" do
  before do
    @eleven_am = Time.parse("2011-1-2 11:00:00")
  end

  it "takes exactly 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second (with stubs)" do
    fake_time = @eleven_am
    Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }
    elapsed_time = measure do
      fake_time += 60  # adds one minute to fake_time
    end
    elapsed_time.should == 60
  end

end
```

I think I'll be able to understand with an example.

Comment: `stub` is used here for `override` the function `now` of `Time` so here instead f return current time which you got from `Time.now` after stub it will return `Time.now + 60` which is define in `fake_time`

Comment: So is it like Object.stub(:replace_this_original_value) {with_this_fake_value} ?

Comment: yes you can override you methods using this stub .......

Answer (score 3):

`stub` is used here for `override` the function `now` of `Time` so here instead of return `current time` which you got from `Time.now` after stub it will return `fake_time`

Answer (score 0):

Note that stub will only 'override' this method only in this one spec. Other specs will respond do `Time.now` properly